# 0 entered in a text input field on a web page gets reset to null

Tags: jquery

When a text input field on my web page gets a value of 0, it changes to null and works just completely fine for all other text input strings.

As per my analysis (using Chrome debugger), the POST saves the data correctly as 0. But, when making a GET request to the same end point, the 0 value is changed to null by then.

```
$.ajaxTransport("iframe", function(options, origOptions, jqXHR) {
    var form = null,
      iframe = null,
      name = "iframe-" + $.now(),
      files = $(options.files).filter(":file:enabled"),
      markers = null,
      accepts = null;

    // This function gets called after a successful submission or an abortion
    // and should revert all changes made to the page to enable the
    // submission via this transport.
    function cleanUp() {
        markers.prop("disabled", false);
        form.remove();
        iframe.one("load", function() { iframe.remove(); });
        iframe.attr("src", "javascript:false;");
    }

    // Remove "iframe" from the data types list so that further processing is
    // based on the content type returned by the server, without attempting an
    // (unsupported) conversion from "iframe" to the actual type.
    options.dataTypes.shift();

    // Use the data from the original AJAX options, as it doesn't seem to be
    // copied over since jQuery 1.7.
    // See https://github.com/cmlenz/jquery-iframe-transport/issues/6
    options.data = origOptions.data;

if (files.length) {
      form = $("<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'></form>").
        hide().attr({action: options.originalURL, target: name});

      // If there is any additional data specified via the `data` option,
      // we add it as hidden fields to the form. This (currently) requires
      // the `processData` option to be set to false so that the data doesn't
      // get serialized to a string.
      if (typeof(options.data) === "string" && options.data.length > 0) {
        $.error("data must not be serialized");
      }
      $.each(options.data || {}, function(name, value) {
        if ($.isPlainObject(value)) {
          name = value.name;
          value = value.value;
        }
        $("<input type='hidden' />").attr({name:  name, value: value}).
          appendTo(form);
      });
```

I expect my saved input value to be persistent as 0, but it changes to null.

Comment: `console.log()` only works on JS Code. You are trying to use it in PHP. Try print_r or var_dump.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. print_r did help me debug.